# Run one Appium test on multiple platforms

Tags: android, ios, cucumber, appium

I am working on an app that is developed both for Android and iOS. I'm using Appium and Cucumber to automate it.

Currently my automation project structure is:

```
android
   |_ appfile.apk
   |_ appium.txt
   |_ features
     |_ step_definitions
        |_ steps.rb
     |_ first_test.feature
ios
   |_ appfile.app
   |_ appium.txt
   |_ features
     |_ step_definitions
        |_ steps.rb
     |_ first_test.feature
```

The test scenario and steps in first_test.feature are identical for android and iOS. What I'm trying to do is merge the two folder structures (android + ios) in a single one, so I don't have to duplicate the code for both sides.

But the problem I'm facing is that the appium.txt file cannot contain definitions for both iOS and Android at the same time. This is the reason why we initially created separate folders for each platform.

Any help or pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution: have only one "features" folder in the root directory, where "android" and "ios" are placed. The ios/android folders will contain only the specific appium.txt and the application pack.

I can control what appium.txt file to load when instantiating the appium driver:

```
@appium_driver ||= Appium::Driver.new(Appium.load_appium_txt({file: 'iOS/appium.txt', verbose: true}))
```

Comment: What about the step definitions? They would have to be implemented (at least in some cases) separately for each platform. How would you load them?

Comment: @robocab See my answer here for a strategy to manage alternative step definitions [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332373](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332373)